# Laravel 5.1 - I used Authentication, but now I need to access logged in user data on a custom controller?

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and have a problem I'm sure I'm being dumb over.

I've used the built in authentication to create a new user.
Now I've created a dashboard area where I want to show user data (I'm building an internal messaging system so I want to get all messages assigned to the logged in user.. and to do that.. I need to get the current User ID.

I'm new as I said.. and I'm still fussy on how and where to use:

```
use path\to\files
```

and how they relate to the framework.. I presume it's just like include or require in 'standard' PHP?

So, how can I get my user information?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('dashboard', $user);
    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found
```

So added this line, which just game the same error:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Auth::user()` in laravel 5. You can access your logged in user details by using `$request->user()`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request) // Inject the Request class in your method
    {
        $user = $request->user()->id; // for example will give you the id of the logged in user
        return view('dashboard', $user);
    }

}
```

As a Sidenote in case you need it again:

For `use` statements you will need to provide the fully qualified class name. This means

```
namespace\Class
```

I'm on mobile right now and don't know the name exactly, but you can have a look at your Auth Class to get the namespace.

Comment: Cheers! Is there any documentation on why/how 'Inject the Request class in your method' works?

Comment: Have a look on laravels and symfonies ioc container

Comment: Perfect... so much to learn... (I'm coming from CI.. don't hate me :p )

Comment: Ah but for the how part, simply have a look in my code example, that's all you need @Beertastic

Answer (score 0):

When trying to use `Auth::user();` you are accesing the `Auth` facade with is not in your `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. Try:

```
function index(){

        dd(\Auth::user());
}
```

Notice de `\` before `Auth`.